# Getting different lines with same stroke in Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass.

Here's how I override the draw method:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.lineWidth = 1
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY+1))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY+1))
UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
path.stroke()
path.close()
```

But the lines appear to be different when the view renders.
Particularly,

When view.frame.height is less than superview.frame.height:
[image: view < superview]

When view.frame.height is greater than superview.frame.height:
[image: view > superview]

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is in **draw(_ rect: CGRect)**, keep in mind that rect will be different. Both your **path.Move** and **path.AddLine** calls refer to this. How are you positioning things in the superview? AutoLayout or Frames?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is right. My code is in draw(_ rect: CGRect). My view is positioned as follows -> UIViewController.view contains a UITableView.tableViewHeader = UIView -> This contains the UIView-subclass which is positioned with AutoLayout.

Comment: So, what is the topmost **actual** rect Y value for the bezier path in each of the times when it is different? Depending on how view.frame.height is pinned to the superview, you may be seeing what you coded. Also, what exactly is the issue? Are you getting the same line except that it is vertically "off by x", or something else?

Comment: I'm getting the same rect for both cases: (0.0, 0.0, 406.0, 441.666666666667) . The UIViewSubclass is pinned to the top, left, and right of the view at UITableView.tableViewHeader, but unbound at the bottom. The issue is the thickness of the lines. One appears to be thicker than the other -- though both should have the same linewidth (1).

Comment: I should mention that that there are two different instances of the same UIView subclass. Where one instance's line has a different thickness than the other (although the drawing method is exactly the same).